# Is it possible to know what page is loading a php version from just viewing the website?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I would like to make a tool that would check what version of PHP the page is loading, I work a lot with wordpress and this would save me a lot of time, Thanks!

Comment: phpinfo() should do what u need http://php.net/phpinfo

Comment: Do you mean on a server you have access to, or on an unrelated third party server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at the HTTP response headers, which may include the `X-Powered-By` header. If it doesn't, there's no real way to find out. E.g.:

```
deceze$ curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 08:53:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.15
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

The above is assuming the question is about figuring out the PHP version of arbitrary 3rd party servers. If you have actual access to the server yourself, there's a ton of ways to find out.

Comment: This is the only answer that answered the actual question! Providing that the question was accurate, about "just viewing the website".

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a php file in your server (FTP) with the following code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This will output the php version as well as other info

http://php.net/phpversion

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo phpversion();
```

use this to return php version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
print_r(apache_response_headers() );
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
 (
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.4.17
)
```

To get apache version:

```
    $version = apache_get_version();
    echo "$version\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Apache/2.2.23 (Fedora)
```